# How to replace elements inside the list in series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like below,

**df1**

```
         col1
0          10
1  [5, 8, 11]
2          15
3          12
4          13
5          33
6    [12, 19]
```

Code to generate this `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[10,[5,8,11],15,12,13,33,[12,19]]})
```

**df2**

```
   col1  col2
0    12     1
1    10     2
2     5     3
3    11    10
4     7     5
5    13     4
6     8     7
```

Code to generate this `df2`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[12,10,5,11,7,13,8],"col2":[1,2,3,10,5,4,7]})
```

I want to replace elements in `df1` with `df2` values.

If the series values contains non list elements, 
I could simply replace with `map`

```
df1['res'] = df1['col1'].map(df2.set_index('col1')["col2"].to_dict())
```

But now this series contains mixed of list and scalar.
How to replace elements in list and scalar values in series in effective way.

**Expected Output**

```
         col1     res
0          10        2
1  [5, 8, 11] [3,7,10]
2          15       15
3          12        1
4          13        4
5          33       33
```

Comment: Did the below solution help? If so, feel free to accept, or ask for clarification.

Comment: @jpp-I was waiting for vectorised solution as you commented it's not possible, I accept the answer :) If you found in future please let me know. If you wish you could consider upvoting my question too...

Comment: I already upvoted your question :). Unfortunately, a vectorised solution isn't possible as long as your series is `dtype=object`. Which will always be the case if you want a `list` in your series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series is of dtype `object`, as it contains `int` and `list` objects. This is inefficient for Pandas and means a vectorised solution won't be possible.

You can create a mapping dictionary and use `pd.Series.apply`. To account for `list` objects, you can catch `TypeError`. You meet this specific error for lists since they are not hashable, and therefore cannot be used as dictionary keys.

```
d = df2.set_index('col1')['col2'].to_dict()

def mapvals(x):
    try:
        return d.get(x, x)
    except TypeError:
        return [d.get(i, i) for i in x]

df1['res'] = df1['col1'].apply(mapvals)

print(df1)

         col1         res
0          10           2
1  [5, 8, 11]  [3, 7, 10]
2          15          15
3          12           1
4          13           4
5          33          33
6    [12, 19]     [1, 19]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is vectorised solution impossible for this kind of problem. I'm seeking to find vectorised solution for this one. because My data set is huge I can't use apply :(. seeking to find vectorised approach for this problem

Comment: @MohamedThasinah, With the way your data is structured, no, it's not possible.